# R - Year-wise percentage graph from 2-D table

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a graph out of the below table. It shows the insured people percentage per year.

[image]

I have tried:

```
tab7 <- table(database$year,database$insured )
tab7
tab7_per <- prop.table(tab7, margin=1)
tab7_per
```

I want to show the change of the percentage over years(x) and to show each dot in every year in a different colour. (to explain my self i need to show each percentage of each dot in every year )

My output keeps showing columns graph instead of lines.

```
dput(head(tab7, 20))

structure(c(4238L, 4400L, 4255L, 3615L, 3311L, 3579L, 3739L, 
3733L, 3690L, 3388L, 5417L, 5429L, 5450L, 5103L, 5264L, 5190L, 
5026L, 5006L, 14297L, 13735L, 13254L, 13708L, 12407L, 12546L, 
12032L, 12298L, 12664L, 12309L, 23321L, 23182L, 23197L, 22731L, 
22752L, 22100L, 22151L, 22222L), .Dim = c(18L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
    "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
    "2006", "2007", "2008"), c("0", "1")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

an update i tried using

`database$age_cat[database$under19==1] <- "below 19 "`

```
database$age_cat[database$under19==0] <- "above 19 "

percentage <- aggregate(insured~age_cat+year,data = database,tab7_per)
ggplot(data = percentage, mapping =aes(x=year,y=insured,color=age_cat)) + geom_point()

z+ scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))
```

but its showing the mean and not the percentage.

Comment: Please paste your data as text, not image.

Comment: See `help('matplot')`.

Comment: @zx8754i i tried but unfortunately it keep showing in a random order sorry for the inconvenient im new to this

Comment: @RuiBarradas i tried it before writing this post for some reason it keep showing columns for each year

Comment: Try using `dput(tab7)` or `dput(head(tab7, n))` where n is sufficient rows to represent your data.  Maybe also show the code you used for the graph attempt. This makes it easier for others to help, tryout and verify solutions. Have a look at [mre] for guidance.

Comment: @Peter thanks for the advice but i cant see how it will help me and an answer to ur question i tried plot and ggplot on my table and my data directly and it didnt help

Comment: Please follow @Peter's advice, it is impossible for us to help you without knowing what **exactly** is in your data set, its structure.

Comment: @RuiBarradas i did out my data set as a pic since i took it from R if i copy paste it it gets mixed

Comment: Run `dput(head(tab7, 20))`, copy the output of that command and post it in the question.

Comment: @RuiBarradas i did like u asked , i need to show both percentages of 0,1 change over the years in a graph

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses function `percent` in package `scales` to format the `y` axis percentages. I also believe that the `table` instruction prior to plotting the data might not be needed.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(tab7)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Var2) %>%
  mutate(Perc = Freq/sum(Freq),
         Var2 = factor(Var2, levels = 0:1, labels = c("No", "Yes"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Perc, fill = Var2)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Percent", fill = "Insured") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]